# How interact with XAML of a CollectionView using MVVM?

Tags: c#, mvvm, maui

For the experts in Xamarin Forms and .net Maui, I am surprised at the lack of real IN DEPH tutorials. Here are some real opportunities LACKING on this framework. I have a CollectionView with posts that have likes, favorite buttons and many other clickable label fonts and buttons. How do I:

1. Change a Label font color inside of CollectionView from MVVM code
2. Change a clicked button color after click inside the CollectionView
3. Change any label text from MVVM inside the CollectionView.

The problem is that InotifypropertyChanged does that identify the individual button or label that was tapped, nor does it changes the properties from MVVM code.

There are 0 tutorials addressing these issues. I also need to change the url of images when tapped. Nothing works. This is frustrating even for me with many years of .net experience.

I am using This code inside the MVVM file does not change the values on the XAML:

```
` 
//using ObsevableCollection to load items to CollectionView
public ObservableCollection<UserHomeModel> Items { get; set; } = new ();

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;    
       
        public void OnPropertyChanged(string name) =>
          PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));



 private string _ViewStatus;
        public string ViewStatus
        {
            get => _ViewStatus;
            set
            {
                _ViewStatus = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ViewStatus));
            }
        }

        private Color favorite; //= Color.Parse("#FFD590");
        public Color Favorite
        {
            get => favorite;
            set
            {
                favorite = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Favorite));
            }
        }`
```

Comment: there are thousands of tutorials, posts, videos, samples, etc showing how to use CollectionView in Xamarin Forms and MAUI.  Based on the very small snippet of code you posted there is no way to know what you might be doing wrong.  Where is the relevant XAML?  What class does the code you posted belong to?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Point me to a tutorial MVVM, CollectionView where I would be able to change the color of a label or button for a specified button or label after a tapped event. There are many tutorials but none explain how to manipulate one specific item inside the collectionview.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59996071/xamarin-forms-change-label-from-collectionview-in-eventhandler

Comment: As Jason suggested, **show the XAML that defines the CollectionView and its ItemTemplate**. My best guess based on the code you've shown so far, is that `Color Favorite` is part of your page's ViewModel. Is that the case? Are you trying to affect colors on all rows of collectionview, or just one? If just one, that has to be in `class UserHomeModel`. In addition to showing XAML, improve your code: **show properties inside of whatever class they are in.**

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve it is part of the model. I use ContentView templates and have tried triggers and visual states. Again, the problem is that the changes have to come from code behind or MVVM. For example I use a DisplayActionSheet() as a select menu to have the user pick an action. The action is then executed in MVVM and the result may need to trigger a numeric counter, color change etc. I can change the XAML from Code behind, but when I scroll, CollectionView changes disappear. If you know how to change one label color in many CollectionView records, please share the code.

Comment: 1) IMPORTANT: You still have not shown **the XAML that defines the CollectionView and its ItemTemplate**. 2) An MVVM way to "change color" is to have a property in the item model (UserHomeModel) that is used in XAML to decide what color, via a Binding. The property does not have to be a color. It might be an integer, that a value converter uses to pick a color. See [value converters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/converters). If that doc isn't enough help, there are many Xamarin examples using IValueConverter. Your converter would return a Color.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve thank you, I use value converters but the changes do not work inside a collectionview.

Comment: And yet you still have not **added to question the relevant XAML**, and in this case show how you attempted to use value converter in a CollectionView's ItemTemplate. We can't help you unless you show EXACTLY what you have done, that did not work. How are we supposed to know what you did wrong, such that the changes do not work inside a collectionview??? I'm not going to make any other suggestions, until you show what you have done, and show what I have asked you to show. I recommend re-reading my comments.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve thank you. I made a small project with a CollectionView, dummy data and three different controls that I want to affect with MVVM. Please download here https://wetransfer.com/downloads/60839f3654ec75f52afa6d3398f397b620230712005023/f4c0d2 . I used WeTransfer to upload.

Comment: While its useful to provide a download link, it is still necessary to add the essential information to the question. (As text that can be copy/pasted by others.) The goal is to have a Q&A that will help others in the future. Links can’t be relied on indefinitely. And having the relevant code/xaml in question is more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

There is serious lack for such interactions, because no MVVM expert will even consider doing this from the "MVVM" code.

Such "color" changes, are usually part of styles and the page XAML.

This is done by DataTriggers, Visual State, Template Selectors, etc.

What you are trying to is breaking more or less every principle of MVVM.

Start here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/triggers

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/datatemplate

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/visual-states

This will cover 99% of your cases.

Comment: H.A.H thank you. Your suggestions do work for XAML changes. I am using data templates and have tried triggers and visual states. Again, the problem is that the changes have to come from code behind or MVVM. For example I use a DisplayActionSheet() as a select menu to have the user pick an action. The action is then executed in MVVM and the result may need to trigger a numeric counter, color change etc. I can change the XAML from Code behind, but  when I scroll, CollectionView changes disappear.  If you know how  to change one label color in many CollectionView records, please share the code.

Comment: @MarcosL may I see your xaml, and the way you set the color of the label?

Comment: thank you. I made a small project with a CollectionView, dummy data and three different controls that I want to affect with MVVM. Please download here https://wetransfer.com/downloads/60839f3654ec75f52afa6d3398f397b620230712005023/f4c0d2 . I used WeTransfer to upload.

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved! The simple answer for me was that when using a separate Model tied to the XAML, **InotifyPropertyChanged needs to be implemented in the Model for the properties I need to change in real time**.

The CollectionView Data is changed in the View Model then you can instantiate the  Model and change the properties you wish to change On the XAML UI right from the View Model.

Comment: Glad to see that you've solved it. You can check [Accept Your Own Answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/) as it will be helpful for those people who are facing the same issue.